# How to add to a list in Firebase without overwriting

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to create a 'Favorites' section in my app where you hit a button and it is added to a user favorites list in firebase. I am using the ionic platform.

I created a factory to handle the favourites as they come in. and i use the getAuth() function to get the unique userID so i can just pull it when the user logs on. This is my attempt but i am not getting the result i wanted which is simply something like :
    < userid >:
{
      0: "fav1"
    1: "fav2"
}

```
.factory('Favourites',function($firebaseArray){
  var ref = new Firebase("https://experiencett.firebaseio.com/");
  var authData = ref.getAuth();
  var favs = $firebaseArray(new Firebase('https://experiencett.firebaseio.com/favourites/'+authData.uid+''));
 return {
   all: function() {
   return favs;
 },
 add: function(){
   var up=new Firebase('https://experiencett.firebaseio.com/favourites/');
   var usersref=up.child(authData.uid);
   usersref.push({3:"paria"});
},
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `push()` you are generating a unique id. While that is great for many use-cases, it is not good here since you want to control the path that is written.

Since you're already constructing the path with `child(authData.uid)` you can simply update it with `update()`:

```
usersref.child(authData.uid).update({3: "paria"});
```

This will either update the existing value at `3` or write the new value for `3`, leaving all other keys under `/users/<uid>` unmodified.

Alternatively if you want to replace the data that already exists at `users/<users>`, you can use `set()` instead of `update()`.

This is all covered in the Firebase JavaScript SDK in the section on [storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing). It is not covered in the AngularFire documentation, since there is nothing specific to Angular about it.

Comment: is it possible to use a variable to place your location example
   
      var nxt=favlist.length+1;
    .....
      usersref.update({nxt:"paria"});

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to pre-create the object: `var obj = {}; obj[nxt] = 'paria'; usersref.update(obj);`